# Getting bad request for missing parameter 'grant_type' even though it's part of my request body

Tags: c#, .net, oauth-2.0, powerbi

I have tried to get access token for PowerBI API with the following method and proper inputs for clientId, clientSecret, username and password but I get Bad Request saying required parameter **'grant_type'** is missing.

```
public static async Task<string> GetToken()
{   ​   
    var client = new RestClient();
​
    var url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token"
    var request = new RestRequest(url, Method.POST, DataFormat.Json);
​
    var body = new
    {
        grant_type = "password",
        client_id = "clientId",
        client_secret = "clientSecret",
        username = "user",
        password = "password",
        resource = "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api"
    };
​
    request.AddJsonBody(body);
​
    var response = await client.ExecutePostAsync(request);
    return response.Content;
}
```

Something wrong with by JSON body or something completely different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request body needs to be form url encoded - not json

If you're using C# I'd recommend using the [Identity model library](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel) to reduce mistakes.

Here is [some sample code](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/aspnetcore1/quickstarts/2_resource_owner_passwords.html)

Comment: Okey. I ended up using `request.AddParameter(...) ` with every body element and then it worked.